# How can I change the dependent variables of a function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

What I want is to define a function which depends of some variables and then get the expression for that same function when it depends of different variables.

My specific case is: (where `u` is the main function and `u0` is a part of it.)

```
u[x_, y_, z_] = ((-I)*Integrate[E^(((I/2)*k*((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2))/z)*u0[x0, y0], y0, {x0, -Infinity, Infinity}])/(z*\[Lambda])

u0[x, y] = P[x, y] Exp[(-I k)/(2 f ) (x^2 + y^2)]
```

And now I want to know how the function changes with the variables: `u[r_, zR_]`, where:

```
 r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
zR = z - f;
```

What I need is a code where I write `u[variables]` and it gives me the main function but with the new variables.

Comment: I think you might want to call your changed-variable version of the function something other than `u`, otherwise Mathematica (and maybe the person reading this question) would have no way to distinguish them!

Comment: For example, you might want to say you want `v` such that `v[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z - f] == u[x, y, z]`.

Comment: Note that your function definitions are also a bit off: they should be of the form `f[x_, y_, ...] = `, not `f[x, y, ...] =`.

Comment: You cannot use pattern objects (`_`) on the RHS of a definition (`Set` or `SetDelayed`).

Comment: But I don't want to get the same function, I want the same structure but with different variables. For example: f[x_] = x^2 , g[y_] = y^2, if I do that I get: f[x_] == g[y_] =x^2

Comment: Are you sure? The analogy to what I'm saying would be: original function: `g[y_] := y^6`, new variable: `q = y^2`, and we want a new version of `g`, `g2`, which is "in terms of this variable", i.e. `g2[q] == g[y]` and therefore `g2[y^2] == g[y]`, so we could take `g2[q_] := q^3`.

Comment: Also, note that you can write `code` by enclosing text in backticks \`like this\`!

Comment: Yes!!! Now I've got it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
ClearAll[r, zR];
r: = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
zR: = z - f;
u0[x_, y_] := PP[x, y] Exp[(-I k)/(2 f) (x^2 + y^2)]
u1[x_, y_,z_] := ((-I)*
Integrate[E^(((I/2)*k*((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2))/z)*u0[x0, y0], 
 y0, {x0, -Infinity, Infinity}])/(z*\[Lambda])
```

You should run:

```
u1[r, zR, z0] /. z -> z0
```